# Only capture tap event from button contained in ListViewItem without triggering item click - UWP Windows 10

Tags: xaml, mvvm, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal, windows-10-mobile

In my UWP app which uses MVVMLight, I have a button contained in my ListViewItem and when clicked I want to display a flyout and provide additional actions for the specific ListViewItem but whenever I tap on the button, I get an error i.e.

```
System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of
type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.TappedRoutedEventArgs' to
type 'MyApp.ViewModels.ItemViewModel'.
at GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command.RelayCommand`1.Execute(Object parameter)
at Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions.Core.InvokeCommandAction.Execute(Object
sender, Object parameter) at
Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity.Interaction.ExecuteActions(Object sender,
ActionCollection actions, Object parameter)
at Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions.Core.EventTr
```

I understand to some extend why it's happening but how I can I fix this? The button contained in my ListViewItem data template is obviously being passed to the parent which is the listview and the DataTrigger that's defined in the Listview is capturing it.

All I want to do is display a flyout when this button is clicked to provide additional options.

```
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid Background="{StaticResource SystemControlBackgroundAccentBrush5}">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Border Grid.Row="0"
                    Grid.Column="0" 
                    Grid.RowSpan="4"
                    Width="90"
                    Height="90"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    Margin="5,5,0,5">
                <Image Width="90" 
                   Height="90" 
                   Source="{Binding Logo}" />
            </Border>
            <Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Margin="5">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" 
                        Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
                    <TextBlock Text="Id:" FontWeight="SemiBold"  Foreground="White" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Subject}" Margin="10,0,0,0" Foreground="White" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </StackPanel>
                <Button Width="30" Height="30" 
                        Command="{Binding AdditionalInfoCommand}" 
                        Grid.RowSpan="4"
                        Grid.Column="1"
                        Margin="0,0,12,0">
                    <Button.Template>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                            <Grid>
                                <Ellipse Stroke="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundAccentBrush}" 
                                         Fill="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundAccentBrush}"
                                         StrokeThickness="2">
                                </Ellipse>
                                <Image Source="ms-appx:///Assets/Information.png" Width="30" Height="30" />
                            </Grid>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Button.Template>
                </Button>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

and my ListView has the following code:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}"
              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}"
              SelectionMode="Single">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
           .... as defined above
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
      <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Tapped">
        <core:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ItemClickCommand}" 
         CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem}" />
      </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
    </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
</ListView>
```

Any ideas on how I can resolve this?

**UPDATE 1:**

I'll re-phrase my question slightly. I've managed to bind the button displayed on the ListViewItem to a specific click event by introducing a RelayCommand (AdditionalInfoCommand) in the item's ViewModel. So now my main problem is the actual error mentioned above which is triggered after AdditionalInfoCommand and I assume it's because it is being captured by the ItemClickCommand. Strange as you would assume that it is using the same ViewModel.

Is there a way to no trigger the itemclick when this button is tapped?

Thanks.

Thierry

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.

When I tap the button inside my ListView DataTemplate, the button is being passed the Item's ViewModel which is correct but then the tap event is bubbled up back to the parent which is captured by:

```
<interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Tapped">
        <core:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ItemClickCommand}"
          CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem}" />
    </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
</interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
```

While there may be a solution to stop the event bubbling, to circumvent the problem, I changed my ItemClickCommand.

It was defined as follows:

```
private RelayCommand<MyItemViewModel> _itemClickCommand;

public RelayCommand<MyItemViewModel> ItemClickCommand
{
    get { return this._itemClickCommand ?? (this._itemClickCommand = 
    new RelayCommand<MyItemViewModel>((viewModel) => 
    ItemClickCommandAction(viewModel))); }
}
```

I simply changed it to:

```
private RelayCommand<object> _itemClickCommand;

public RelayCommand<object> ItemClickCommand
{
   get { return this._itemClickCommand ?? (this._itemClickCommand = 
   new RelayCommand<object>((viewModel) => 
   ItemClickCommandAction(viewModel))); }
}
```

I then changed the ItemClickCommandAction to take in an `object` instead of `MyItemViewModel` and now, within the method, I check the `type` of the ViewModel being passed:

```
private void ItemClickCommandAction(object currentObject)
{
    if (currentObject is MyItemViewModel)
    {
        //go to next page
    }
}
```